# Trouble proving surjective, injective, or bijection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Please help me find way to determine whether these function are surjective, injective, bijective or non either algebraically or with calculus.

1. $r: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, where $r(x)=7x$

I think this is injective only since if I let $r(a)=r(b)$ then $7a=7b$ which then $a=b$

2. $k: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ , where $k(x)=x^2 + x$

I think this is also injective only, however I am not able to show the proof.

I have $k(a)=k(b)$ then

$a^2+a = b^2+b$

$a^2-b^2+a-b=0$

$(a-b)(a+b)+(a-b)=0$

$(a-b)(a+b+1)=0$

then $(a-b)=0$ which leads to $a=b$ but $(a+b+1)$ does not equal $0$, which confusing me on how to prove it.

3. $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ , where $f(a/b)=a-b$ . Note that $a/b$ is written in lowest terms in order to be sure $f$ is a function

I believe this is surjective but I'm not sure how to prove it

4. $s: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ , where $s(a/b)=ab$ . Note that $a/b$ is written in lowest terms in order to be sure $s$ is a function.

I believe this is surjective but I'm not sure how to prove it

Comment: You seem to be completely ignoring:  Is 1 surjective or not; Is 2 surjective or not; Is 3 surjective or not; Is 4 injective or not.  Why are you not considering those?

Answer (score 1):

$r(x)=7x$ is not surjective as, $1$ doesn't belong into range of $r$. $r$ is injective, as you have shown.

$k(x)=x^{2}+x$ is injective, as $k(x)=k(y) \implies x^{2}+x=y^{2}+y \implies (x-y)(x+y+1)=0 \implies x=y $ (As, $x+y+1\neq 0 $  , since $x,y$ are natural numbers ).
$k$ is not surjective , as $1$ doesn't belong into range of $k$

$f(\frac{a}{b})=a-b $ is not injective, as $f(\frac{2}{3})=-1=f(\frac{4}{5})$ .
For proving, $f$ is surjective, we have to show for any $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ , there is $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(\frac{a}{b})=c$ , this can be easily done by taking $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c+1}{1}$.

$s(\frac{a}{b})=ab $ is not injective, as , $s(\frac{2}{1})=2=s(\frac{1}{2})$
For proving, $s$ is surjective,we have to show for any $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ , there is $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $s(\frac{a}{b})=c$ , this can be also easily done by taking $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's injective because  $r(x) = r(y)\implies 7x = 7y \implies x=y$.

There are two ways to prove something is injective. i) Directly:  $r(x) =r(y) \implies x = y$.  or ii) Contrapositively: $x\ne y \implies r(x)=r(y)$.  We could have proven if $x\ne y$ then $x-y \ne 0$ so then $7(x-y) \ne 0$ and $7x - 7x \ne 0$ and $r(x) =7x \ne 7y = r(y)$.

But you haven't shown it isnt surjective.  Which it obviously isn't as it only maps to multiples of $7$ and nothing else.

But to prove it formally:  If $w$ is not a multiple of $7$ then $r(x) = 7x = w$ where $x$ is an integer is not possible.  so $r$ is not surjective.

OR.... if $w$ is not a multiple of $7$ then $w = 7k + i$ for some integers $k, i$ were $i=1,2....,6$ and if $r(x) = 7x = w = 7k + i$ then $x = k + \frac i7$ but $\frac i7$ is not an integer so $r(x)$ is impossible.

Or simply, *a single counter example is a proof of non attribute*.  Let $w= 1$ then $r(x) = 7x = 1$ can only happen if $x = \frac 17$ but $\frac 17$ is not an integer.

2. you are on the way to proving it is injective.

If $k(a) = k(b)$ then $a^2 + a = b^2 + b$ so $a^2 -b^2 +a-b =0$ so $(a-b)(a+b+1) =0$.

That means either $a-b = 0$ *OR* that $a+b + 1 = 0$.

But $a,b \in \mathbb N$ so $a,b \ge 0$ so $a+b + 1 \ge 1> 0$ so $a+b + 1 \ne 0$.  So that means we *must* have $a-b =0$ or $a=b$.

So if $k(a) = k(b)$ then $a=b$ so $k$ is injective.  But is it surjective?

If $w \in \mathbb N$ and we have $k(a) =w$ then $w = a^2 + a = a(a+1)$.  Is that always possible?  What if $w$ is prime?  Then that's only possible if $a=1$ and .... $a + 1 = 2$ and $w=2$.  As a single counterexample is a proof, $k(a) = a^2 + a = p$ for any prime number other than $2$ is impossible so $k$ is not surjective.

Those aren't the *only* counter-examples.  In fact for any $w$ so that $n^2 < w < (n+1)^2$ then $w = n^2 + m$ and if $m\ne n$ then $w= n^2 + m=a^2 + a$ is impossible.  If $a < n$ then $w=a^2 + (n^2-a^2)+m$ and $(n^2-a^2)+m > a$; and if $a =n$ then $m \ne n=a$.  And if $a > n$ then $a^2 +a> (n+1)^2> n^2 + m = w$.  But that's a much harder proof.

3. If $f(\frac ab) = f(\frac cd)$ then $a-b = c-d$ which... does that mean $(a,b)=(c,d)$?  The answer is of course not.

For example we can have $5-3 = 7-5$ so $f(\frac 53) = f(\frac 75)$ but $\frac 53\ne \frac 75$ so as a single counterexample disproves a statement, $f$ is not injective.

But is it surjective.  If $n\in \mathbb Z$ can we alwys find an $\frac ab$ in lowest terms where $a-b = n$?

Sure.  Let $a= n+1; b = 1$.  Then $f(n+1) = f(\frac {n+1}1) = (n+1) =1 = n$.  So for any $n\in \mathbb Z$ there is a $q\in \mathbb Q$ so that $f(q) = n$.  So $f$ is surjective.

Note because $f$ is *not* injective there are other sollutions to $f(q)=n$.  If $n$ is odd we could have $f(\frac {n+2}2) = (n+2)-2 = n$.  If $n$ is not divisible by prime $p$ then $f((\frac {n+p}p ) = n$.

4. Notice  for any $n$ we have $s(\frac 1n) = 1\cdot n=n$ so $f$ is surjective. QED. End of story.

But it's probably not injective.

If $s(\frac ab) = ab$ and $s(\frac cd) = cd$ and we have $ab = cd$ does that mean $(a,b) = (c,d)$?

Of course not. As $ab = ba$ we could know we have $s(\frac ab) = ab =s(\frac ba)$ but $\frac ab \ne \frac ba$.

But those are all.  If $p, q,r $ are primes then $s(\frac 1{pqr}) = s(\frac p{qr}) = s(\frac q{pr})=s(\frac r{pq})=s(pqr)=s(\frac{pq}r)=s(\frac {pr}q)=s(\frac {rq}p) = pqr$.

So not injective.

Answer (score 0):

For Q2, since $(a+b+1)$ does not equal $0$ and $(a-b)(a+b+1)=0$, we must have $a-b=0$.

For Q3 and Q4, work backwards. Given $n \in \mathbb Z$, can you find $a/b$ such that $f(a/b)=n$ or $s(a/b)=n$?

Remember to also prove that the functions are not of the other type (e.g. $r, k$ are not surjective)

Comment: For Q2, so both (a-b) and (a+b+!) doesn't have to equal to zero?

Comment: The product of 2 numbers is zero when at least one of them is. So there is no need for both of them to be zero.

Comment: $0*23 = 0$ but $23 \ne 0$.  If you have $(a-b)(a+b+1)=0$ you must have *either* $a-b =0$ *OR* that $a+b+1 = 0$.  But you *CANT* have $a+b+1 = 0$ because $a,b$ are natural.  If $k$ were $\mathbb Z \to Z$ it wouldn't be injective as we could have $a-b \ne 0$ but $a+b+1 = 0$.  For example.  if $a = -b-1$ then $f(5) = 5^2 + 5 = 30$ and $f(-6) = (-6)^2 +(-6) = 30$.  And $f(5) = f(-6)$.